# Imagen SVG interfiere en el evento 'click' del botón

Tags: angular, typescript

Al poner un evento 'click' al botón funciona perfectamente pero al incrustar una imagen SVG dentro del botón esta interfiere ya que al dar 'click' se lo hace en la imagen SVG. Como puedo arreglar esto para que funcione el evento click solo en el botón y no interfiera la imagen al sobreponerse al botón. Uso Angular 9 con Typescript.

**Botón con la imagen SVG**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " id={{eps.idExamen}} name='btn-delete' >
     <svg class="bi bi-trash" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>    
     </svg>
  </button>
```

**Evento del Botón**

```
 this.eventManager.addGlobalEventListener('document', 'click', (evento) => {
       if(evento.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button'){
             if(evento.target.name.toLowerCase() === 'btn-delete'){
                //Eliminar registro
               }
             }
 });
```

Comment: porque no usas la directiva `click` para añadir el click en el botón?

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes añadir el evento 'click' a la imagen y disparar un 'click' sobre su padre, que en este caso sería el botón que la contiene.

Comment: @hawks el problema es que el `click` lo recibe la imagen y no el botón, aunque ponga o use la directiva en el botón, esta nunca se disparará porque el elemento 'button' no recibe esa acción

Comment: sisi eso lo tengo claro que aunque usara la directiva pasaría lo mismo solo queria saber porque añade el click así. Anyway gracias:)

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el manual de CSS y analizando encontré la forma de anular los clicks en los SVGs con lo siguiente:

```
svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```